# Can not build flutter app using Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I am trying to build a Flutter app using Android Studio, but there is an error with message follow occurred.

```bash
> Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDevelopmentRelease
lib/main.dart: Error: Error when reading 'lib/main.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.

package:my_app/main.dart: Error: No 'main' method found.
Try adding a method named 'main' to your program.
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
```

At this step, I click the button build in Android Studio to build the project. I know there is a specific configuration in the build.gradle to indicate the entry point, which helps the Android Studio build the project. Please, help me write the configuration to run the project

---

My build.gradle file in my project

```
android {
    namespace "com.my.app"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.my.app"
       
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        if (System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH")) {
            release {
                storeFile file(System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH"))
                keyAlias System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_ALIAS")
                keyPassword System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD")
                storePassword System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
            }
        } else {
            release {
                keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
                keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
                storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
                storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            }
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        production {
            dimension "default"
            applicationIdSuffix ""
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appName               : "App Name",
                    'flutterMainDartEntry': 'lib/main_production.dart'
            ]
        }
        staging {
            dimension "default"
            applicationIdSuffix ".stg"
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appName               : "[STG] App Name",
                    'flutterMainDartEntry': 'lib/main_staging.dart',
            ]
        }
        development {
            dimension "default"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appName               : "[DEV] App Name",
                    'flutterMainDartEntry': 'lib/main_development.dart',
            ]
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your flutter compilation started at main.dart file then it will work on android studio.

or you did not change the main.dart file .. So it you have to sync the gradle file at Android studio.
So sync the Gradle and wait for Completion of the sync. If sync fail then you will not able to run the flutter project at android studio.